# How to delete rows that satisfy some criteria in an excel spreadsheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I would like to create a "reduced" version of an Excel (xlsx) spreadsheet (i.e. by removing some rows according to some criterion), and I'd like to know if this can be done with `openpyxl`.

In (pythonish) pseudo-code, what I want to do would look something like:

```
wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook('/path/to/workbook.xlsx')
sh = wb.get_sheet_by_name('someworksheet')

# weed out the rows of sh according to somecriterion
sh.rows[:] = [r for r in sh.rows if somecriterion(r)]

# save the workbook, with the weeded-out sheet
wb.save('/path/to/workbook_reduced.xlsx')
```

Can something like this be done with `openpyxl`, and if so, how?

Answer (score 20):

2018 update: I was searching how to delete a row today and found that the functionality is added in openpyxl 2.5.0-b2.  Just tried and it worked perfectly. 
Here's the link where I found the answer: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/964/delete_rows-does-not-work-on-deleting

And here's the syntax to delete one row:

```
ws.delete_rows(index, 1)
```

where: 
'ws' is the worksheet,
'index' is the row number, and
'1' is the number of rows to delete.

There's also the ability to delete columns, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Be aware that delete_rows() actually moves the rows below up. That means that after deleting a row, all the other rows below it have a different rownumber. So remember this when iterating over all the rows.

Comment: @NielsHenkens How do you suggest that can be solved, like if I have multiple rows that need to be deleted?

Comment: It has Ben a while since I used this, but from memory: If you are, for example, looping over all your rows, you could reduce your index number (or not increment it) after a row deletion. Such that the next row in your iteration had the same row number as the row that you just deleted.

Comment: Works so slow. Is there any way to delete rows as a bunch, e.g. 2, 5, 10 row?

Answer (score 3):

Internally `openpyxl` does not seem to have a concept of 'rows' it works with cells and keeps track of the dimensions and if you use [`Worksheet.rows`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.rows) it calculates a 2D array of cells from that. You can mutate the array, but it doesn't change the Worksheet.

If you want to do this within the Worksheet, you need to copy the values from the old position to the new position, and set the value of the cells that are no longer needed to `''` or `None` and call [`Worksheet.garbage_collect()`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.garbage_collect).

If your dataset is small and of uniform nature (all strings e.g.), you might be better of copying the relevant cell (content) to a new worksheet, remove the old one and set the title of the new one to the title of the just deleted one.

The most elegant thing to do, IMHO, would be to extend `Worksheet` or a subclass with a `delete_rows` method. I would implement such a method by changing the coordinates of its `Cell`s in place. But this could break if `openpyxl` internals change.

Comment: Setting cell values to '' or None doesn't delete them, much less the entire row.

Comment: But calling `garbage_collect` will remove the trailing empty rows.