# Delete all empty rows from Excel file without overwriting file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I have a script that updates a spreadsheet with current events, and deletes them after they are over x days old. The spreadsheet gets very big. I have logic that appends rows when new events come in, and deletes rows over x days old. The most recent events are at the bottom of the spreadsheet.

People work on this spreadsheet, and at times highlight rows. I would like to keep that highlighting such that when the script runs, and row 80 (highlighted) gets moved up to row 40, row 40 is highlighted and 80 is not. The issue I am having is that 80 also stays highlighted. So I need a function to delete all rows that do not have text (but may have highlighting).

This is what I have so far:

```
def deleteEmptyRows(file, sheet_name):
    """Remove empty rows from bottom of excel file.
    Issue: If I highlight row 80 and the script runs,
    moving that row to row 40, both row 40 and 80 will
    be highlighted.
    Solution: delete empty rows (only containing highlighting)
    at the bottom of the excel file. This also helps keep
    the file smaller."""

    book = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine='openpyxl')
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = {ws.title: ws for ws in book.worksheets}
    maxRow = len(pd.read_excel(file)) + 2
    sheetLen = int("".join([x for x in writer.sheets[sheet_name].calculate_dimension().split(':')[1] 
                            if x.isalpha() == False]))



    openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_rows(writer.sheets[sheet_name]
                                                        ,idx=maxRow, amount=(sheetLen-maxRow))

    print('delete {} rows starting at row {}'.format((sheetLen-maxRow), maxRow))

    writer.save()
```

But this is not removing the highlighting from the bottom of the spreadsheet or deleting the rows, event though the numbers in the print statement look correct.

Comment: I tried so many times to accomplish this and was never successful, I eventually found the bottom answer on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14904977/how-to-delete-rows-that-satisfy-some-criteria-in-an-excel-spreadsheet

Comment: is that solution outdated? I don't see garbage_collect()

Comment: Yes, that solution is using an older version of openpyxl. Unfortunately, I never successfully accomplished deleting row formats in the current version.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you're using Pandas here at all. openpyxl will let you delete rows.

Comment: I was using pandas because openpyxl was telling me that my max_row was different than it actually was, possibly because of the highlighting.

Comment: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/editing_worksheets.html#deletinng-rows-and-columns

Comment: I'm already using delete_rows in my function.