# openpyxl delete rows based on condition

Tags: python, openpyxl, python-3.7

I am trying to iterate through the rows in a spreadsheet and delete rows where column 7 is equal to 'Prospect Enterprise'.

I can't quite figure out the logic. Appreciate someone helping me figure it out.

I have tried this:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb1 = load_workbook('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active
for row in ws1.iter_rows():
    if row[6].value == 'Prospect Enterprise':
        #print(row)
        ws1.delete_rows(row)
wb1.save('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen_ProspectDeleted.xlsx')
```

and get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-50c694086280> in <module>
      5     if row[6].value == 'Prospect Enterprise':
      6         #print(row)
----> 7         ws1.delete_rows(row)
      8 wb1.save('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen_ProspectDeleted.xlsx')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py in delete_rows(self, idx, amount)
    706         """
    707 
--> 708         remainder = _gutter(idx, amount, self.max_row)
    709 
    710         self._move_cells(min_row=idx+amount, offset=-amount, row_or_col="row")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py in _gutter(idx, offset, max_val)
    877     range(cells_to_delete) > range(cell_to_be_moved)
    878     """
--> 879     gutter = range(max(max_val+1-offset, idx), min(idx+offset, max_val)+1)
    880     return gutter

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

But the print rows does print out the row I want to delete:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb1 = load_workbook('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active
for row in ws1.iter_rows():
    if row[6].value == 'Prospect Enterprise':
        print(row)
        #ws1.delete_rows(row)
#wb1.save('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen_ProspectDeleted.xlsx')
```

```
(<Cell 'report1571089659791'.A5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.B5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.C5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.D5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.E5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.F5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.G5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.H5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.I5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.J5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.K5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.L5>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.M5>)
(<Cell 'report1571089659791'.A8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.B8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.C8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.D8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.E8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.F8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.G8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.H8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.I8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.J8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.K8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.L8>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.M8>)
(<Cell 'report1571089659791'.A18>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.B18>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.C18>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.D18>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.E18>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.F18>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.G18>, <Cell 'report1571089659791'.H18>,

And so on
```

I have also tried:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb1 = load_workbook('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen.xlsx')
ws1 = wb1.active
for row in ws1.iter_rows(min_col=7, max_col=7, min_row=2, max_row = None):
    for cell in row:
        if cell.value == 'Prospect Enterprise':
            ws1.delete_rows(row)
            #print(row)
wb1.save('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen_ProspectDeleted.xlsx')
```

but get this exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-57e660d2328f> in <module>
      6     for cell in row:
      7         if cell.value == 'Prospect Enterprise':
----> 8             ws1.delete_rows(row)
      9             #print(row)
     10 wb1.save('C:\\transfer\\AllSitesOpen_ProspectDeleted.xlsx')

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py in delete_rows(self, idx, amount)
    706         """
    707 
--> 708         remainder = _gutter(idx, amount, self.max_row)
    709 
    710         self._move_cells(min_row=idx+amount, offset=-amount, row_or_col="row")

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py in _gutter(idx, offset, max_val)
    877     range(cells_to_delete) > range(cell_to_be_moved)
    878     """
--> 879     gutter = range(max(max_val+1-offset, idx), min(idx+offset, max_val)+1)
    880     return gutter

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'
```

Comment: Change `for cell in row: ; if cell.value == ...` to `if row[6].value == ...`. I'm not sure if it's safe to `.delete_rows(...` while iterating with `iter_rows(...`. Ref: [Worksheet.delete_rows](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.delete_rows)

Comment: ***`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'int'`***: The parameter for `ws1.delete_rows(row)` have to be `int`. Change to `ws1.delete_rows(row[6].row)`.

Comment: @stovfl Thank so much! That worked. So that TypeError is telling me what exactly? I am not sure how to interpret it. What is this greater sign for example?  '>'  I see though that it has to be an integer. So the the code must been trying to delete rows based on coordinates or something rather than the row number I presume. Is that the idea?

Comment: ***"TypeError is telling me what exactly?"***: The function `.delete_rows(...` expects a parameter of type `int`, but the `row` is of type `tuple of Cell`. The function does not support auto converting from `tuple of Cell` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

According to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49370237/3911355 and the documentation it looks like you want to pass the index (`idx`) of the row to delete, not the row itself. So, you might want to have an `enum` on your row loop, or have some other way to track which row number you want to delete.

It might be better to construct a list of the row numbers that meet your deletion criteria, and delete them all at once after going through the worksheet once.